# How can I completly clear all browser history, caches, and keychain passwords?

Tags: history, browser-history

Borrowed a laptop from a friend and would like to clear all internet history and clear all flash caches etc, and forget passwords from the keychain (if it stores these?)

Been using incognito mostly but yeah, and weird cookies stored in a random subolder or anything?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Safari, go to `Safari -> Reset Safari` and select check every box. Then click reset.

If you're using Chrome, click Cmd-Shift-Del and check the desired boxes. Here's an image:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not seeing "Rest Safari" anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the password for the user account that you are using now (assuming it's an account with Administrator privileges), why not go to System Preferences: Users & Groups, and create a new user account with Administrator privileges. Then log out  and log back in under the new account you've just created. You'll have a completely new user account with a blank Keychain and no cookies and nothing in any caches.

Comment: I believe the OP's talking about **browser** caches, keychains, etc.